# Programmatically load CSS using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve the following:

- I have a server-side script that generates CSS code depending on GET parameters
- On user request a JS should now do the following

  - Load a new CSS file
  - When loading is done, fade to the newly loaded style

Problem here is the last step.

It is no problem to add a new CSS file to the DOM, but **how do I know when the browser finished loading the file**?
I cannot start animations using the newly loaded styles until the file is actually loaded.

Alternatively: Is it possible to load a CSS file using Async Requests, and inject the CSS code into the DOM using Javascript without parsing it by hand?

Thank you very much!

Dennis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are a nice library for this kind of filters...

maybe you can give that a try:

> [**Yep Nope**](http://yepnopejs.com/)
>
> Yepnope is an asynchronous conditional resource loader that's super-fast, and allows you to load only the scripts that your users need.

Comment: This library looks great! I will give it a try, Thank you very much balexandre!

Comment: No need to thank... upvote for that, and if that the answer you were looking for, make the answer as correct answer :)

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is quite old, but in case anyone Googles this, here is a function that lets you define a callback to let you know when the stylesheet is loaded:

```
    var css = function(url, callback) {

         var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
         var cssnode = document.createElement('link');

         cssnode.type = 'text/css';
         cssnode.rel = 'stylesheet';
         cssnode.href = url;

         cssnode.onreadystatechange = callback;
         cssnode.onload = callback;

         head.appendChild(cssnode);
     }
```

Comment: Cool, do you know which browsers support this?

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was looking for. The core problem is getting notified when the file finished loading.

Comment: Then you can use jquery.load method to get notified when the script has been completed downloaded on the client computer. You can perform any action using the callback it provides.

Comment: this was simple and allowed me to inject googlefonts CSS into a hosted solution that does not allow me to set external CSS by default.